# Output from gdal_translate projwin is different from geoserver WCS GetCoverage request?

Tags: geoserver, gdal-translate, wcs, subset, output

I've a hard time understanding which one should be the correct result by gdal_translate or GeoServer.

My system (Ubuntu 22.04) has:

- GDAL 3.4.1
- Geoserver 2.22 running on Tomcat on port 9090

I have a small tiff file (link to download at the bottom of this thread) in EPSG:4326, then I wanted to have a small subset on Lat and Long axes from it by running:

```
 gdal_translate -projwin 137.915315044103 -36.51629558851893 154.64770004642423 -40.081875882617666 test.tif gdal.tif
```

```
 curl 'http://localhost:9090/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&format=image/tiff&coverageId=test_raster:output&subset=Lat(-40.081875882617666,-36.51629558851893)&subset=Long(137.915315044103,154.64770004642423)' -o geoserver.tiff
```

- Then gdalinfo gdal.tif returns:

```
Size is 17, 4
```

and gdalinfo geoserver.tif returns

```
Size is 17, 3
```

- Also the geo bbox of gdal.tif and geoserver.tif are different.
  First file gives:

```
Upper Left  ( 136.9750000, -35.9750000)
```

Second file gives:

```
Upper Left  ( 137.9750000, -36.9750000)
```

More importantly, the pixels are shifted from gdal.tif at the top to geoserver.tif at the bottom which you can see from this image:

[image]

Here is the link to download test.tif, gdal.tif and geoserver.tif https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dawCy38FMwx4J7OQsky-gAHHOXsMuDcy/view?usp=sharing

Which result (gdal.tif or geoserver.tif) should be correct?

Full gdalinfo for `gdal.tif`

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: gdal.tif
Size is 17, 4
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
   Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (136.974999999999994,-35.975000000000001)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 136.9750000, -35.9750000) (136d58'30.00"E, 35d58'30.00"S)
Lower Left  ( 136.9750000, -39.9750000) (136d58'30.00"E, 39d58'30.00"S)
Upper Right ( 153.9750000, -35.9750000) (153d58'30.00"E, 35d58'30.00"S)
Lower Right ( 153.9750000, -39.9750000) (153d58'30.00"E, 39d58'30.00"S)
Center      ( 145.4750000, -37.9750000) (145d28'30.00"E, 37d58'30.00"S)
Band 1 Block=17x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

and for `geoserver.tif`:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: geoserver.tif
Size is 17, 3
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
   Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (137.974999999999994,-36.975000000000001)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 137.9750000, -36.9750000) (137d58'30.00"E, 36d58'30.00"S)
Lower Left  ( 137.9750000, -39.9750000) (137d58'30.00"E, 39d58'30.00"S)
Upper Right ( 154.9750000, -36.9750000) (154d58'30.00"E, 36d58'30.00"S)
Lower Right ( 154.9750000, -39.9750000) (154d58'30.00"E, 39d58'30.00"S)
Center      ( 146.4750000, -38.4750000) (146d28'30.00"E, 38d28'30.00"S)
Band 1 Block=16x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

**UPDATE 2:** I tested with geotools 29 snapshot with this code below and it returns grid size 18 x 5 instead

```
        File file = new File("/home/aaa/Downloads/temp/test.tif");

        Hints hint = new Hints();
        hint.put(Hints.DEFAULT_COORDINATE_REFERENCE_SYSTEM, WGS84);
        hint.put(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);

        GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(file, hint);
        GridCoverage2D coverage = reader.read(null);

        CoverageProcessor processor = CoverageProcessor.getInstance();

        final ParameterValueGroup param = processor.getOperation("CoverageCrop").getParameters();

        // 137.915315044103 -36.51629558851893 154.64770004642423 -40.081875882617666
        double minLong = 137.915315044103;
        double maxLong = 154.64770004642423;
        double minLat = -40.081875882617666;
        double maxLat = -36.51629558851893;

        final GeneralEnvelope crop = new GeneralEnvelope(new GeographicBoundingBoxImpl(minLong, maxLong,
                minLat, maxLat));

        ReferencedEnvelope envelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(new Envelope(minLong, maxLong,
                minLat, maxLat), WGS84);

        param.parameter("Source").setValue(coverage);
        param.parameter("Envelope").setValue(envelope);

        GridCoverage2D cropped = (GridCoverage2D) processor.doOperation(param);

        GridCoverageFactory gcf = new GridCoverageFactory();
        GridCoverage2D gc = gcf.create("name", cropped.getRenderedImage(), cropped.getEnvelope());
        String url = "/tmp/geotools.tif";
        File outputFile = new File(url);
        GeoTiffWriter writer = new GeoTiffWriter(outputFile);
        writer.write(gc, null);
        writer.dispose();
```

with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo /tmp/geotools.tif 
Size is 18, 5
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (136.974999999999994,-35.975000000000001)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 136.9750000, -35.9750000) (136d58'30.00"E, 35d58'30.00"S)
Lower Left  ( 136.9750000, -40.9750000) (136d58'30.00"E, 40d58'30.00"S)
Upper Right ( 154.9750000, -35.9750000) (154d58'30.00"E, 35d58'30.00"S)
Lower Right ( 154.9750000, -40.9750000) (154d58'30.00"E, 40d58'30.00"S)
Center      ( 145.9750000, -38.4750000) (145d58'30.00"E, 38d28'30.00"S)
Band 1 Block=18x5 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

Comment: can you add the `gdalinfo` result on both output files

Comment: @IanTurton I updated the description, please have a look

Comment: looks like someone has an off by one error

Comment: @IanTurton it is clear from the image but I don't know whose tool is correct.

Comment: that is the hard bit, I guess you could try to look in a 3rd tool or construct an image so that you could tell which pixel is where

Comment: @IanTurton all other tools AFAIK rely on gdal as well so I don't know which 3rd tool can be tested. If you happened to know a tool that is great.

Comment: Can't help I'm afraid - everything I use is gdal or geotools based. Maybe an ESRI tool?

Comment: @IanTurton I think you are the main contributor of geotools. Please help me to find the source code (formula) where the cropping raster is done from github repo: https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/main/modules. This project is too big and I don't even know where to search for it.

Comment: I'd start at https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/wcs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wcs/responses/GeoTIFFCoverageResponseDelegate.java and work back from there

Comment: @IanTurton I think I found it at https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/42b54ef8c77b8729ce78c5d4982633dc83ada4ac/modules/library/coverage/src/main/java/org/geotools/coverage/processing/operation/Crop.java#L282

Comment: @IanTurton I updated the description with a test to crop the GeoTiff with GeoTools 29-snapshot directly and it returned also different result from both gdal and geoserver. This is frustrating.

Comment: look for the conversion of the envelope (BBOX) to pixels - I would guess that someone is rounding up and others rounding down. Try drawing the bbox on the map.

Comment: Possibly a difference based on treating pixel as Point vs pixel as area between GeoServer WCS and GDAL.   It would be interesting to also note any difference if you use GDAL to call the GeoServer WCS as a data source, rather than a copy of the TIFF

Comment: Have you already tried to run the gdal_translate command against the WCS service as nmtoken suggested? Add `--debug on --config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES` into your gdal_translate command so you can capture the GetCoverage request that GDAL is sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I considered the result from geoserver is the correct one and I confirmed that with R `raster` package.

Fortunately, I found the formula from R `raster` which I could understand.
Here is the `R` code to return the same subset like geoserver WCS `GetCoverage` subset.

Copied from:

- https://github.com/rspatial/raster/blob/f71e83b9838ca79c05c4b0a881b970966b2d1191/R/xyCell.R#L95
- https://github.com/rspatial/raster/blob/805e5e80f0a7363e583b2486c914bdd300b47728/R/crop.R#L53

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(raster))

x <- raster(ncols=44, nrows=36)

# min_long, min_lat, max_long, max_lat

xmin <- 111.975
ymin <- -44.975
xmax <- 155.975
ymax <- -8.975

extent(x) <- extent(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

# min_long, min_lat, max_long, max_lat

input_xmin <- {}
input_ymin <- {}
input_xmax <- {}
input_ymax <- {}

out <- extent(input_xmin, input_xmax, input_ymin, input_ymax)

col1 <- colFromX(x, xmin(out)+0.5*xres(x))
col2 <- colFromX(x, xmax(out)-0.5*xres(x))


# gridIndex1 < gridIndex2

row1 <- rowFromY(x, ymax(out)-0.5*yres(x))
row2 <- rowFromY(x, ymin(out)+0.5*yres(x))

col1 <- col1 - 1
col2 <- col2 - 1
row1 <- row1 - 1
row2 <- row2 - 1

pixel_x <- col2 - col1 + 1
pixel_y <- row2 - row1 + 1

geo_lower_bound_x <- xmin + (col1) * xres(x)
geo_lower_bound_y <- ymax - (row2 + 1) * yres(x)
geo_upper_bound_x <- xmin + (col2 + 1) * xres(x)
geo_upper_bound_y <- ymax - (row1) * yres(x)

cat(pixel_x, pixel_y, geo_lower_bound_x, geo_lower_bound_y, geo_upper_bound_x, geo_upper_bound_y)
```

And the python test code to calculate the grid extent from the geo-referenced extent based on the above formula:

```
import os

# nrow = 10, col = 10, ncell = 100
# resx = 36, resy = 18
# extent = -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

xmin = -180
xmax = 180
ymin = -90
ymax = 90
xres = 36
yres = 18

def colFromX(x):
    colnr = int( (x - xmin) / xres ) + 1
    return colnr

def rowFromY(y):
    rownr = 1 + ( int( (ymax - y) / yres ) )
    return rownr
    

def cal(subset_xmin, subset_ymin, subset_xmax, subset_ymax):
    col1 = colFromX(subset_xmin + 0.5 * xres) 
    col2 = colFromX(subset_xmax - 0.5 * xres)
    row1 = rowFromY(subset_ymax - 0.5 * yres) 
    row2 = rowFromY(subset_ymin + 0.5 * yres)
    
    print(col1 - 1, col2 - 1, row1 - 1, row2 - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no shift in the pixels of the GDAL TIFF and the GeoServer TIFF if the images are looked as georeferenced for example with QGIS. The difference between 3 and 4 rows comes from the way how the programs deal with the pixels which do not fall completely inside the projwin/subset. GDAL includes the intersected pixels into the result while GeoServer WCS does not.

[image]

The behavior of the `-projwin` in gdal_translate is defined by the GDAL developers so probably it is "correct", even there has been some changes during the lifetile

> In GDAL 2.1.0 and 2.1.1, using -projwin with coordinates not aligned
> with pixels will result in a sub-pixel shift. This has been corrected
> in later versions. When selecting non-nearest neighbour resampling,
> starting with GDAL 2.1.0, sub-pixel accuracy is however used to get
> better results.

GeoServer WCS should act as is defined in the WCS standard.

> A.1.32 GetCoverage trimming within coverage limits Test id:
> /conf/core/getCoverage-request-trim-within-extent
>
> Test Purpose: Requirement
> /req/core/getCoverage-request-trim-within-extent:
>
> Let the extent of the coverage’s gml:Envelope along the dimension
> specified in the trim request range from L to H. Then, for the trim
> bounds trimLow and trimHigh the following shall hold:
>
> L <= trimLow <= trimHigh <= H.

In the GeoServer response the trimHigh value is larger than the maximum latitude

```
trimHigh = -36.51629558851893
H        = -36.9750000
```

It looks that the GeoServer response is not correct by the WCS 2.0 standard. Comparison with gdal_translate that is using the GTiff driver is not really relevant.